# How to safely rename our files and all the references to it - Xcode 10?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to rename my files in Xcode, but I have no luck.

In a BedTime folder, I have 2 files.

- Schedule.storyboard
- ScheduleViewController.swift

[image]

I'm trying to rename both of these files from

- Schedule.storyboard
- ScheduleViewController.swift

to

- Bedtime.storyboard
- BedtimeViewController.swift

Also all the codes that references to

[image]

I need to start referencing to `BedtimeViewController.swift`

I've tried a replace all option, I got an error after that.

How do safely rename our files in Xcode?

Answer (score 3):

1. Change name of storyboard in Project Navigator
2. Update Main storyboard property in Info.plist (if this is the main storyboard)
3. Change name of swift file in Project Navigator
4. Right click class name in the same swift file and do Refactor->Rename and enter new name for class